# Exceção com Converter de um selectOneMenu do Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Criei um selectOneMenu dinamico que recebe uma Lista de objeto Autor que implementa Serializable.
O código é o seguinte:

**XHTML do selectOneMenu**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="autor_selecionado" value="#{pragaBean.autor}" style="width: 19%;" 
                                         required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Selecione um Autor">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um autor" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems   value="#{autorBean.autores}" var="autor"
                                             itemLabel="#{autor.nome}" 
                                             itemValue="#{autor}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Classe de Converter**

```
public class ClasseConverters {

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Autor.class)
    public class AutorConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
                return (Autor) uiComponent.getAttributes().get(value);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
            if (value instanceof Autor) {
                Autor entity = (Autor) value;
                if (entity instanceof Autor && entity.getId() != null) {
                    uiComponent.getAttributes().put(entity.getId().toString(), entity);
                    return entity.getId().toString();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    //outros converters ...
}
```

**Exceção que ocorre ao carregar página**

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: pacote.util.ClasseConverters$AutorConverter
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:423)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.newConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1829)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1361)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:163)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getOptionAsString(InputRenderer.java:146)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeOption(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:353)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:93)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pacote.util.ClasseConverters$AutorConverter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3074)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar um conversor para cada entidade da seguinte forma:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "ConversorAutor")
public class AutorConverter implements Converter {
```

No seu xhtml utilize a propriedade converter no selectOneMenu. Ficará assim:

```
                   <p:selectOneMenu id="autor_selecionado" value="#{pragaBean.autor}" style="width: 19%;" 
                                     converter="ConversorAutor"
                                     required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Selecione um Autor">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um autor" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems   value="#{autorBean.autores}" var="autor"
                                         itemLabel="#{autor.nome}" 
                                         itemValue="#{autor}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Nunca utilizei vários conversores dentro de uma única classe, pode ser que este seja o seu problema.

Abraços

Comment: O erro continua. :(

Comment: Tente criar uma unica classe converter para a sua entidade. Aqui usamos assim! Tenta testar, pode ser que funcione! :D

Comment: Me tambem é estranha esse tipo de arquitetura, com mais de um converter dentro de uma unica classe.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente era isso mesmo.Funcionnou, Gilvan responda como resposta para marcar como resolvido. grato!

Comment: Ola. Eu editei esta resposta mesmo. Portanto pode marcar esta mesmo como correta! Obrigado e abraços

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas vai aqui uma explicação que ficou faltando:
A forma como as classes converter foram declaradas, elas são **classes internas** de  `ClasseConverters`.
Um objeto de uma classe interna só pode ser instanciado se ele estiver **associado a um objeto da classe externa** (classes internas têm acesso `private` à objetos da classe externa). Ex:

```
ClasseConverters converters = new ClasseConverters();
ClasseConverters.AutorConverter autorConverter = converters.new AutorConverter();
```

O JSF, porém, não vai criar um objeto da classe externa, por isso a exception.

Para resolver, as classes internas precisam ser `static`. Classes internas estáticas não precisam estar associados a um objeto da classe externa:

```
public class ClasseConverters {

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Autor.class)
    public static class AutorConverter implements Converter { //static

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
                return (Autor) uiComponent.getAttributes().get(value);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
            if (value instanceof Autor) {
                Autor entity = (Autor) value;
                if (entity instanceof Autor && entity.getId() != null) {
                    uiComponent.getAttributes().put(entity.getId().toString(), entity);
                    return entity.getId().toString();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    //outros converters ...
}
```